# How to remove grey shadow around popups and tooltips?

Tags: java, popup, tooltip, border

I tried remove shadow border around popups and tooltips by change LookAndFeel and creating custom toolips for components - but any of this doesn't work.

One of approaches which I used is *compound border* with the specified outside and inside borders.

First one in LaF:

```
Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 1);
Border margin = new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10);
UIManager.getDefaults().put("ToolTip.border",new CompoundBorder(border, margin))
```

Second one by override createToolTip() in specific component:

```
@Override
public JToolTip createToolTip() {
    JToolTip tip = super.createToolTip();
    tip.setBackground(Colors.BLUE_TINT_LIGHT);
    tip.setForeground(Colors.TEXT_DARK_STEEL);
    Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 1);
    Border margin = new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10);
    tip.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(border, margin));
    return tip;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In LaF section there is the initialization of **ShadowPopupBorder** which used for tooltips, popups, and modal dialogs borders. I modified **paintBorder** and added an additional check if a component object is an instance of JTooltip class  - works now.

```
/**
 * Paints the border for the specified component with the specified
 * position and size.
 */
@Override
public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    // fake drop shadow effect in case of heavy weight popups
    JComponent popup = (JComponent) c;
    Image hShadowBg = (Image) popup.getClientProperty(ShadowPopupFactory.PROP_HORIZONTAL_BACKGROUND);
    if (hShadowBg != null) {
        g.drawImage(hShadowBg, x, y + height - 5, c);
    }
    Image vShadowBg = (Image) popup.getClientProperty(ShadowPopupFactory.PROP_VERTICAL_BACKGROUND);
    if (vShadowBg != null) {
        g.drawImage(vShadowBg, x + width - 5, y, c);
    }

    // draw drop shadow
    g.drawImage(shadow, x +  5, y + height - 5, x + 10, y + height, 0, 6, 5, 11, null, c);
    g.drawImage(shadow, x + 10, y + height - 5, x + width - 5, y + height, 5, 6, 6, 11, null, c);
    g.drawImage(shadow, x + width - 5, y + 5, x + width, y + 10, 6, 0, 11, 5, null, c);
    g.drawImage(shadow, x + width - 5, y + 10, x + width, y + height - 5, 6, 5, 11, 6, null, c);
    g.drawImage(shadow, x + width - 5, y + height - 5, x + width, y + height, 6, 6, 11, 11, null, c);
}
```

Comment: If there is no shadow border used - in  LookAndFeel initialization just set empty border:

      UIManager.getDefaults().put("ToolTip.border", BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());

It will affect all ToolTip objects around  application